# Spooky computer game from late 90s/2000 where you fight skeleton pirates at the end

Tags: story-identification, video-games

This game has been haunting me for **years** now. I can't find it anywhere.
I've googled so many things and details but I can't find a single clue.
so this is my last hope...

I played this game on my family's computer when I was a young kid.
It was on a CD. I was born in 1993 so I played it when I was a bit older I gues but I have no idea how old the game already was by then.
I am also from Belgium but I don’t know if that matters.

Here's everything I remember from it:

- I believe it was kind of a point and click game because I remember having to click around on things and it telling you stuff about them. I think there was also a lot of stuff you could click on that told you things that didn't realy matter?
- Main character was a young boy? maybe? unsure.
- I don't think it was a 3rd person view. I believe you didn't see the main character often, though I might be wrong.
- I am unsure if it was 2D or 3D, maybe a bit of a mix?
- I remember it being dark and kinda dirty looking.
- I think it took place on a ship maybe? Like a pirate ship or something. At the beginning of the game you went through rooms and towards the end I think you were on the deck.
- At the start somewhere you had to like lift a bed or something and there was a minigame where you had to squash cockroaches or bugs or something against a timer in order to advance.
- A part where you had to zipline over something, a hole maybe?
- A place with big rotting meat slabs hanging from hooks with flies around it.
- A kitchen where you had to mix some goopy colored stuff into the right colors I think?
  In the kitchen there was also 3 mugs (?) with faces. and when you clicked on them they each sang a different tune on repeat, till you clicked them again. so you could make them sing together or separately.
  This part I remember really well, the stupid little tune they sang, because I remember thinking it was funny as a child.
- A minigame on the ship deck (?) where you had to shoot a bar of soap from a cannon into a bucket. But the bucket was on a rope and you had to try and get it in the bucket by trying to get the bucket to the right height vertically and angling the cannon JUST right. This part was like a side view of the thing,  and you could only move the bucket up and down and change the cannon's angle. (I remember this part taking a while)
- I think the ending was a battle maybe? I remember skeleton pirates you had to shoot in a little shooting minigame where they appeared from different places on the screen and you had to click them in time I think?
- I also remember having to climb the ship’s mast.

This is all I remember I think.
The longer ago, the more I wonder if my memories are 100% correct, so take this with a grain of salt I guess.

Fingers crossed someone out there sees this and knows what this is. I really want to see it again.

Comment: Can you remember whether it was a PC or console game? If console, which one. This will narrow the question down a bit.

Comment: I played it on the computer. it was on a CD.

Comment: sure sounded like Secret of Monkey Island

Comment: @NKCampbell and it now sounds like a bad rip off of SoMI...

Answer (score 11):

I shared this post on Twitter and a friend found what it was!
It's [Voodoo kid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voodoo_Kid)!

[image: The cover of Voodoo Kid, showing a pirate ship and a floating skull]

> The unnamed protagonist (who can be chosen to be either a boy or a girl) is magically transported aboard a haunted ship where the player must make his or her way through the vessel and confront Captain Baron Saturday.
>
> The protagonist wakes up in the hold of the ship where they meet Baron Saturday's zombie butler. After the protagonist helps him find Baron Saturday's hat, the butler decides that the protagonist could potentially free the souls captured by the Baron and free the crew. To do so the protagonist needs to assemble the map, which will allow him/her to direct the ship to the land of the living, instead of the island of lost souls, where the Baron is currently sailing. The protagonist proceeds from the hold of the ship to the infirmary, then the kitchen, then the dining room, and finally the deck. Along the way he/she collects the entire map and escapes elemental traps set by the baron by using several loa which turns the protagonist into a spirit like form which he/she uses to deactivate the trap. After changing the course of the ship, the butler reveals that the Baron controls the ship telepathically, and the protagonist has to defeat the Baron to change the course. The protagonist climbs up the mast and frees the souls the Baron has captured before confronting the Baron. The protagonist manages to defeat the Baron using knowledge of the elements. The protagonist then wakes up, the whole adventure seemingly a dream, before the voodoo container of souls the Baron used appears as a reward for the protagonist's bravery.

Now to find how I can play this again! :D

Comment: _The Archive_ [has it](https://archive.org/details/Voodoo_Kid_InfoGrames). And no need to close your question, but you might want to click the check mark next to it. Welcome to [fantasy.se], by the way.

Comment: Just as a side note, as a self-answer, you will have to wait 48 hours after asking the question to be able to accept it. Clicking earlier will just tell you how much time is left.

Comment: Heh... for those who speak French, this is the famed *loa*, Baron Samedi (the one that the Bond character is named after, or maybe is given the ending), Samedi being French for "Saturday".